# Puppeteer controlled Chrome fails file upload on DocuSign

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, docusignapi

This is a weird one for me as I've done plenty of file uploads via puppeteer without any issues. However, when attempting to do so in DocuSign - it fails. No errors on puppeteer side, just DocuSign seems to be uploading file (there's a loader and a few seconds delay) and then rejecting it. I tested it with headless:false mode without closing the browser at the end of the process in order to be able to attempt manual file upload in the same form (just in case file location was wrongly declared), but result was the same.

However, if the whole puppeteer flow is done manually, there are no issues. Thus it seems that there is some security setting within the puppeteer default setup which triggers DocuSign's checks. Here's my puppeteer process:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: '[path to chrome]',
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
        headless: false
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/112.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 WAIT_UNTIL=load");
    await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(30000);
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1300, height: 800});
    await page.emulateTimezone('America/Chicago');
    await page.goto('[URL]',{ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
    [......]
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        document.querySelector('.attach-tab-content').click();
    });
    await page.waitForSelector('input[name=document].signing-input-file',{visible: true});
    const inputUploadHandletemp = await page.$('input[name=document].signing-input-file');
    await inputUploadHandletemp.uploadFile([path to file on the server]);
    return;
    await browser.close();
})();
```

Maybe somebody else already had that issue in the past and found a solution? I'm clutching at straws here, but one can never know.

Thank you in advance!

** DocuSign URL and form cannot be shared publicly.

Comment: Can you create a sample docusign URL? It's hard to help without something to examine, test and work with. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, @ggorlen, document is generated via DocuSign's powerforms (which aren't available as any sort of trial for me to even attempt generating a demo page) and initiated and accessible via multipage flow on another website with private login information. DocuSign's custom link then is session attached and has a very short expiry time. As mentioned in my original question, this is a long shot just in case somebody already faced this before and found a solution.

Comment: Why not have puppeteer use the DocuSign API?

Comment: I know you said you've done this before with puppeteer, so this may be irrelevant but just in case it matters.... your code has this line, `await inputUploadHandletemp.uploadFile([path to file on the server]);`... where you say, _[path to file on the server]_, shouldn't this be the path to the file on the client trying to upload the document? Or maybe when you say server you mean the client you run your puppeteer process on and not the DocuSign server. Either way, are you sure the puppeteer process is locating the correct file?

Comment: @quaabaam thank you for your input. It is path to file on the server as it's part of a multipage/multisite flow starting with specific file being generated on our server end and then attempting to upload it onto the DocuSign form in the last step.

Comment: @LarryK, correctly if I'm wrong, but isn't DocuSign API used to create e-signature documents rather than fill in existing ones created by somebody else?

Comment: What is your use case for using puppeteer? Are you attempting to programmatically manipulate the signing ceremony via puppeteer? Unless you're limiting yourself to the developer's environment as part of an automated test of an application, the signing ceremony is strictly for use by humans.

Comment: @LarryK no no, nothing of this sort. A form that is required for signing spans over 4 pages and has a lot of specific data and calculated values within it. The requirement is to pre-fill the form and upload a support file, then submit it with 'finalise later' flag, so user can login, review and sign it manually.

Comment: If your software is creating/sending the envelope, then you can use the API to pre-fill the form. Otherwise, you're right we don't have an API to help a signer upload docs/enter data into a form. If it's your form, you could send it. If someone else is sending you a very complicated form, you'd need to discuss with them. Maybe they'll give you an API to pre-fill the form.

Comment: @LarryK It's a third-party website that initiates the form, and we have no control over it nor access to it's controls/API. I guess we'll create a workaround providing the document to the customer so they can attach it to the form manually before signing it.

Comment: Can you use Selenium/WebDriver instead? that one I know worked for DocuSign signing

Comment: Hi @InbarGazit, thanks for the suggestion. The project has been completed without the document upload, so perhaps we will look into using Selenium/WebDriver in the future.